# I got empty response from create album in facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i have this URL ..

```
https://graph.facebook.com/602414132/albums?access_token=123005381082600|2.FUPHmHF4kfDPly2GRPYDeg__.3600.1298228400-602414132|1JUKjvfo1Ri5s04x9v_vzf-sS8c&type=post&name=refacingme
```

when i using Chrome i get empty response :

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

from where do you think the error is coming ??

Comment: have you taken extended permission for user photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not taken [Extended Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) of [user_photos](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). Take extended permission then you will not receive empty array

Answer (score 2):

It is true, I just fixed this bug a few days ago myself. The user must grant Extended Permissions for user_photos on your app. A few ways to do this:

1) Update your app info in FB Developer tab and add Extended permissions to your app. This will ask new users who register to give certain permissions before joining.

2) Alternatively, if the user has already added the app you can ask the user for permissions using the Javascript SDK call FB.login while they are in the app. (see code below)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
      // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
      console.log("user is logged in and granted some permissions.")
  } else {
    // User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.
    console.log("he failed to login or something")
  }
}, {scope:'user_photos'});
```

This route requires you have set up the Facebook JavaScript SDK